# Writing Bitmap to string insted of FILE* or XImage to PNG

Tags: c, linux, bitmap, png

i converted the output XImage of my code to Bitmap, but the output file is massive, so i thought about compressing it using lzrw
i use this code to write the bitmap to file

```
fwrite(&bmpFileHeader, sizeof(bmpFileHeader), 1, fp);
fwrite(&bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader), 1, fp);
fwrite(pImage->data, 4*pImage->width*pImage->height, 1, fp);
```

is there anyway i could write it to a (char *) insted of (FILE *) so i can use lzrw compression on it?
or even better, some way to convert the XImage to PNG directly...

thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `memcpy` instead of `fwrite`

```
char* tmp = buf;
memcpy(tmp, &bmpFileHeader, sizeof(bmpFileHeader));
tmp += sizeof(bmpFileHeader);
memcpy(tmp, &bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader));
tmp += sizeof(bmpInfoHeader);
memcpy(tmp, pImage->data, 4*pImage->width*pImage->height);
```

EDIT: I update code, thaks @bdk for pointing out

Comment: didnt work :S, if i tried to save tmp to file it doesnt work!

Comment: You should save not tmp, but buf

Comment: nope my fault, i should have subtracted the whole size from tmp after adding it to it, if u know what i mean... works now, thx :D

Answer (score 0):

For the in-memory copy, use `memcpy` as DReJ says, but if you want to save an image as a PNG, you could do worse than looking into a nice simple PNG library like LodePNG:

http://members.gamedev.net/lode/projects/LodePNG/

I wouldn't waste time re-doing the compression side of things myself if there was an easy alternative -- there are more important problems you can be working on.

---

EDIT - For what it's worth, my code to save PNGs using LodePNG looks like this:

```
void PNGSaver::save_image24(const std::string& filename, const Image24_CPtr& image)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
    encode_png(image, buffer);
    LodePNG::saveFile(buffer, filename);
}

void PNGSaver::encode_png(const Image24_CPtr& image, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer)
{
    int width = image->width();
    int height = image->height();
    const int pixelCount = width*height;

    // Construct the image data array.
    std::vector<unsigned char> data(pixelCount*4);
    unsigned char *p = &data[0];
    for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
        for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
        {
            Pixel24 pixel = (*image)(x,y);
            *p      = pixel.r();
            *(p+1)  = pixel.g();
            *(p+2)  = pixel.b();
            *(p+3)  = 255;
            p += 4;
        }

    // Encode the PNG.
    LodePNG::encode(buffer, &data[0], width, height);
}
```

Comment: seems awesome, but i got no idea how to save XImage using this library, i checked the samples, none would show how to do what i need:(...

Comment: @killercode: The relevant sample is Example 3 in the C++ examples, btw.

Comment: Image Data? thats an XImage struct?, is this the way to convert XImage into PNG? or Bitmap to PNG?

Comment: man, thats too much, will slow down everything... almost useless, u got no idea how to convert XImage to PNG?

Comment: @killercode: What is your underlying goal here? Your original question doesn't mention speed as an issue. If you're doing something like trying to save a video of what's going on in your program, I can see there might be a speed issue, or if your images are really huge. But for normal size images, this is all blisteringly fast -- so pin down for us what your actual problem is.

Comment: the actual problem is size, and speed, both, i need to take a screen shot and save it to be transfered to the other side, thats y i care about the size... and lzrw didnt save much size either, so im looking for some how to convert XImage to PNG or JPG or anything small

Comment: @killercode: Transfer it to the other side of what? Do you mean transfer it over a network? In that case, I'd have thought there was a good chance that the limiting factor was probably network bandwidth, not the time taken to save the image. Supposing it's a 1024x768 24-bit image, i.e. a bit over 2MB uncompressed, sending that over a normal broadband connection is going to be substantially slower than compressing it first and then sending it, even if the compression takes a bit of time. In this case, you're claiming that converting to BMP before compressing is the limiting factor -- you sure?

Comment: well ok, i see ur point, can u tell me how to do it in c then? BMP to PNG? cause i know nothing about vectors and stuff, i got the bmp as a (char *) as u can see above, thanks.

Comment: @killercode: See Example 3 in http://members.gamedev.net/lode/projects/LodePNG/lodepng_examples.c

Comment: "This example encodes a PNG containing a generated texture" ?

Comment: @killercode: Yup -- it shows you how to fill the array with an image (one it generates in this instance) and then encodes it as a PNG. To convert a BMP to a PNG, you just have to write the BMP into the array instead (making sure to get the various components in the right order) and then do the same thing. The example shows you everything you need to know. Try playing around with it a bit and you'll figure it out -- how do you think I figured it out originally?